# Nested IIF statement issue

Tags: sql-server

Here is the whole statement:

```
(IIF(i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales<1,1,(IIF(i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales)) * (i.StockTurnoverCoefitient-n.OVER_SECOND_RANGE))<0,0,(i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales) * (i.StockTurnoverCoefitient-n.OVER_SECOND_RANGE) Loss
```

and getting error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '('.

What I want to get is: if `i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales` value is less than one give me one, else:if multiplication of `i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales` and `(i.StockTurnoverCoefitient-n.OVER_SECOND_RANGE)` is less than zero give me zero. otherwise give me the multiplied value.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or SQL Reporting Services?

Comment: You need to check your parentheses I think. See: IIF(i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales) - that's the entire IIF statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses were a bit crazy. Perhaps lay it out on separate lines for the condition, true and false:

```
   IIF( 
     i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales<1, 
     1,
     IIF(
       i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales * (i.StockTurnoverCoefitient-n.OVER_SECOND_RANGE)<0,
       0, 
       i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales * (i.StockTurnoverCoefitient-n.OVER_SECOND_RANGE)
     ) 
   ) Loss
```

If your SQLserver supports GREATEST it might be simpler to do:

```
   IIF( 
     i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales<1, 
     1,
     GREATEST(0, i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales * (i.StockTurnoverCoefitient-n.OVER_SECOND_RANGE))
   ) Loss
```

ps; laying your original statement out with indentation makes it easy to see what went wrong:

```
(
  IIF(
    i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales<1,
    1,
    (
      IIF(
        i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales
      )
    ) * (i.StockTurnoverCoefitient-n.OVER_SECOND_RANGE)
  )<0,
  0,
  (i.AvgMonthlyCostOfSales) * (i.StockTurnoverCoefitient-n.OVER_SECOND_RANGE) Loss
```

it doesn't come back to indent level 0, and you have `)` paired with `IIF`, an `IIF` that has no bool condition and no true/false etc

Comment: thanks, parentheses was the problem but good not figure out where exactly:)

Comment: Look at the final code block in my answer; you can see it doesn't come back to indent level 0 so that's one problem, and the IIF in the middle of the block doesn't have 3 arguments